# The polynomial function changed to a set consisting of terms of polynomial function

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, formatting, polynomials

I have the following polynomial function
$$f= x_{1,2} x_{2,4}+x_{1,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4}+x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4}+x_{1,3} x_{3,4}+x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,4}$$

I want to convert the polynomial function to set consisting of terms of polynomial function as follows,

$$\{x_{1,2} x_{2,4},x_{1,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4},x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4},x_{1,3} x_{3,4},x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,4}\}$$

Then, delete terms that contain another terms in the set.

$$x_{1,2} x_{2,4}\subset x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4}$$

so we delete $x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4}$ and we get,

$$S=\{x_{1,2} x_{2,4},x_{1,3} x_{3,4},x_{1,3} x_{3,2} x_{2,4},x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,4}\}$$

the mathematica code of the polynomial function $f$

```
f=Subscript[x, 1, 2] Subscript[x, 2, 4] + 
 Subscript[x, 1, 3] Subscript[x, 2, 4] Subscript[x, 3, 2] + 
 Subscript[x, 1, 2] Subscript[x, 2, 3] Subscript[x, 2, 4] Subscript[x,
   3, 2] + Subscript[x, 1, 3] Subscript[x, 3, 4] + 
 Subscript[x, 1, 2] Subscript[x, 2, 3] Subscript[x, 3, 4]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't $S$ contain $x_{1,3}x_{3,4}$?

Comment: @FalafelPita This is a watery mistake thanks for a note. see new update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates) + [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy):

```
baseSet[f_] := DeleteDuplicates[
    SortBy[MonomialList[f], {Head, Length}],
    Denominator[#2/#1]==1&
]
```

For your example:

```
baseSet[f] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{x_{1,2} x_{2,4},x_{1,3} x_{3,4},x_{1,2} x_{2,3} x_{3,4},x_{1,3} x_{2,4} x_{3,2}\right\}$

Comment: Thank you very much for this right answer

Answer (score 7):

This method is overkill for the given example but could be useful for larger problems of this type. It uses two steps, both with non-System context functions. The first is to get the monomials as lists of exponent vectors and corresponding coefficients (the latter of which we will ignore). Then we use a function that effectively finds the minimal exponent vectors, discarding the rest.

```
f = x[1, 2] x[2, 4] + x[1, 3] x[2, 4] x[3, 2] + 
   x[1, 2] x[2, 3] x[2, 4] x[3, 2] + x[1, 3] x[3, 4] + 
   x[1, 2] x[2, 3] x[3, 4];
```

Here is the list of monomial/coefficient pairs along with the ordering of variables that was used to create it (useful for converting back to monomials but I am omitting that step).

```
dtl = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[f, Variables[f]]

(* Out[291]= {{{{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 1}, {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   1}, {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 1}, {{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
   1}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, 1}}, {x[1, 2], x[2, 4], x[1, 3],
  x[3, 2], x[2, 3], x[3, 4]}} *)
```

Here we pick out our exponent vectors.

```
monoms = dtl[[1, All, 1]]

(* Out[293]= {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

And now we get the minimal elements.

```
Internal`ListMin[monoms]

(* Out[301]= {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}} *)
```

Some day I'll advocate for making that `ListMin` into a System-context function.

Comment: May I ask what ``Internal`ListMin`` does?  Is it fair to say that it eliminates a subset of of rows so that the output matrix has `MatrixRank` equal to number of rows?

Comment: Given a list of lists of real values, all of the same length, `Internal\`ListMin` removes any that has all elements greater or equal to elements of another. In effect if finds minimal elements. If the notion of a "Pareto front" is familiar, it is useful for finding those elements that give such a front. Lower hull supporting set (not necessarily convex) might be another way to view it. (Whether these help one to understand the function depends on one's familiarity with them, I realize.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. But why isn't there an analogous ``ListMax`` functionality internally?

Comment: @user688486 Since `ListMin` is an internal function, there's no good reason to add what amounts to syntactic sugar for the "max" counterpart. It would just be `-Internal\`ListMin[-list]`.